# What is the Stack Exchange membership management system?

Tags: discussion, architecture

I read about Stack Exchange software and hardware features in here. What is the Stack Exchange membership management system?

Do you use a customized [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) default membership system, or have you developed a new membership management system?

Comment: It's all made in-house.

Comment: @nhinkle, but what languages on what platforms?

Comment: you may wish to read https://stackoverflow.blog/ or https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/